# Joining same room more then once and clients in a room

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm trying to figure out what happens if the clients emits to join the same room more then once, To test and find answer on this I wanted initially to find out how many clients room has after same clients send more then one emit for joining the room, but Rooms chapter in wiki https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Rooms is outdated. When I try to use "io.sockets.clients('room')" I get error "Object # has no method 'clients'".

So I got two questions:
1. what happens if client tries to join same room more then once? Will he get emits for that room for each time he has tried to join?
2. How can I find out which clients are in a room?

Im using socket.io v1.0.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got an answer on this question at [socket.io github](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1544).

1. As per [this](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L219) line of code, the socket will receive emits only once. The socket is added to a room only once, and if another attempt is made for the same socket to join the room, this attempt will be ignored.
2. There is currently no public API for getting the clients, and there is some discussion ongoing in [#1428](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/pull/1428). If you really need to get them, for some reason, you can fetch the actual clients from the adapter, assuming you are not using the redis adapter like so:

   ```
   socket.join('test room');
   var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['test room'];
   console.log(clients);
   for (var clientId in clients) {
     console.log(io.sockets.connected[clientId]);
   }
   ```

Comment: +1 for not being able to get the clients in the room.  It I ended up doing the same fix you suggested in #2 of your answer

Comment: Is this ignoring has been in the Socket.io 0.9 or is this new in 1.0? Because I like the idea of being ignored if the user is already has been joined the room.

Comment: In v1.3.5 clients is undefined.

Comment: Good to know a socket can only connect to 1 room, was just testing it out in a project. Thanks for providing the code snippet!

Comment: @NickKenens - No, a socket can join to multiple rooms. What the answer suggests is that the 'emit' will be done only once irrespective of multiple tries to join the same room

Answer (score 0):

Fixed getting clients in a room at socket.io ~1.4.5 like this:

```
    socket.join('test room');
    var room = io.sockets.adapter.rooms['test room'];
    console.log(room);
    for (var socketId in room.sockets) {
      console.log(io.sockets.connected[socketId]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its working fine and does not gives any error,it ignores the second request for joining the room from that socket which is already in the room.**

I have actually tried and implemented a solution where 
when user click on message notification it joins that specific room from which the notification came and, and when he sends very first message he again join that specific room (It is because I have build a Chat-Directive in AngularJS).

**Client Side**

1) User Open Notification

```
Socket.emit('JoinRoomWithThsID', notification.ConversationID);
```

2) user Sends First Message in that room

```
Socket.emit('patientChatRoomMessage', adminmessage);
```